# Azure DevOps self hosted agent reports wrong version for NPM

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, azure-devops

We have updated Node to version 10.16.3 and NPM to version 6.11.3 (all the latest at this time) on our Windows based self hosted agent.

However, in a job run logs, we see that the agent reports version 6.9.0 for NPM, which is the default version for Node 10.16.3 installation.
[image: Wrong version reported]

Inside the VM where the hosted agent is, if I run 'npm' in the CMD, I get the latest version for NPM. Also, if I run the same command that the agent is running to get the version, I still get the correct version for NPM:

[image: Correct version]

What could be wrong here? 
The reason we want the latest version of NPM is because our builds run faster with it.

Thank you!

Comment: In my side, the node.js version for hosted agent(VS2017,VS2019) are all 6.9.0. https://imgur.com/a/FeSHE5l Same with the npm task result. Not sure how's your hosted agent?

Comment: 6.9.0 is the NPM version, not Node. I want it to be 6.11.3.

Comment: node version 6.11.3?For agent, the node version can be 10.16.3 which you mentioned in your first sentence.

Comment: Merlin, please read the question carefully. I said I am using Node 10.16.3
I want the NPM version to be 6.11.3

Comment: Yes, this is what I get firstly, in my first comment, I share the screenshot which want to express that for hosted agent, the latest version is 6.9.0, don’t know how do you get 6.11.3 from the hosted agent. In addition, apologies for my expression incorrectly. I wrote npm version as node.js version in my first comment.

Comment: Merlin, by running "npm install -g npm" on the machine. This will update NPM to latest version.

Comment: If you use this command to upgrade the npm version, then execute npm task in the same agent job, the npm version the task used will be 6.11.3. Isn’t this same with yours l? In addition, do you mind I modify your question to add this details in it?  Thus other so users could get your puzzle and the reproduce steps more clearly.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT you tried in Microsoft Hosted Agent (VS2017 etc.), the OP use **Self** Hosted agent in his private PC. It's totally different. please re-read the question.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I know this, self agent is what he run with the task. But, as he said “Inside the VM where the hosted agent is”,  my first comment is about this.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT he has his own VM,  he installed their self agent. what he wrote `hosted` he meant to self agent in his own pc, not MS agents.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I suggest some details of question should better be edit. You know, in VSTS, hosted agent does not equal with self agent. Because firstly, I got the meaning” he is using self agent to run npm task”. But after the first pic, he mentioned that he tried the command in hosted agent. This should mislead me and let me misunderstand what he was doing. Apologize

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT You are right! the question should be updated.

Comment: We have check our backend. All normal on our side and did not find this version mismatch. As you mentioned "if I run the same command that the agent is running to get the version", did you ever try like this: https://imgur.com/a/6DlYRAq ? (If convenient, we can talk in chat for further troubleshoting.)I tried all in self agent, and all of them display 6.11.3.

Comment: Okay Merlin, I added you to my room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200347/gorgi-azure-devops-help

Comment: @GorgiRankovski, Sorry for did not receive notification. I have been in room. Would wait for your reply.

Comment: Our team check the source code completely again, we think this issue does not caused by this task. How many agents on the pool you chosen to run the pipeline? If several, you need ensure the npm version of VM which the agent is running in is 6.11.3. In addition, hope you can share the screenshots about run pipeline and its result like this: https://imgur.com/a/6DlYRAq.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @MerlinLiang-MSFT. We have figured out the problem and fixed it. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have had a very amateur approach to this problem. When we are logging in through RDP, we are using the user 'agent' and all installations are scoped to that user. However, the agent is using the NetworkService user, which has its own scope for NPM and Node.

The fix was basically to add step in our build pipeline to check for latest version of NPM and install it in case it is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I got caught out by this too. Because it runs under the NetworkService account, it can't read the global folder, so has it's own little copy/cache at

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

My easiest way to get back up and running, was to just manually upgrade the npm at that location using the following command:

```
npm install --prefix C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm  npm
```